# Difference between using ls and find to loop over files in a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, find, ls

I'm not sure I understand exactly why:

```
for f in `find . -name "strain_flame_00*.dat"`; do
   echo $f
   mybase=`basename $f .dat`
   echo $mybase
done
```

works and:

```
for f in `ls strain_flame_00*.dat`; do
   echo $f
   mybase=`basename $f .dat`
   echo $mybase
done
```

does not, i.e. the filename does not get stripped of the suffix. I think it's because what comes out of `ls` is formatted differently but I'm not sure. I even tried to put `eval` in front of ls...

Comment: If all you have is a simple glob then why would you use *either*?

Comment: Sure but I'd like to understand why the different behavior...

Comment: Hm, have your tried to `unalias ls` (or use `\ls`)? It just plainly works here...

Comment: Argh !!! alias ls='ls -Fh --color=always' I forgot I had this. Feeling dumb now... I'm guessing the formatting screws things up right? Thank you anyway !

Comment: Never parse the output of `ls`!

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: You also might use `find . -name "strain_flame_00*.dat" -exec basename "{}" .dat \;` to carry out a command on each matched file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct way to iterate over filenames here would be

```
for f in strain_flame_00*.dat; do
   echo "$f"
   mybase=$(basename "$f" .dat)
   echo "$mybase"
done
```

Using `for` with a glob pattern, and then quoting all references to the filename is the safest way to use filenames that may have whitespace.

Comment: Note that this is not safe when too many files are in the directory -  you may reach bash's limit.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, never parse the output of the `ls` command.

If you MUST use `ls` and you DON'T know what `ls` alias is out there, then do this:

```
(
COLUMNS=
LANG=
NLSPATH=
GLOBIGNORE=
LS_COLORS=
TZ=
unset ls
for f in `ls -1 strain_flame_00*.dat`; do
  echo $f
  mybase=`basename $f .dat`
  echo $mybase
done
)
```

It is surrounded by parenthesis to protect existing environment, aliases and shell variables.

Various environment names were NUKED (as `ls` does look those up).

One unalias command (self-explanatory).

One unset command (again, protection against scrupulous over-lording 'ls' function).

Now, you can see why NOT to use the 'ls'.

Comment: instead of unaliasing (there may be an `ls` function), use `command ls`

Answer (score 2):

Another difference that hasn't been mentioned yet is that `find` is recursive search by default, whereas `ls` is not. (even though both can be told to do recursive / non-recursive through options; and `find` can be told to recurse up to a specified depth)

And, as others have mentioned, if it can be achieved by [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), you should avoid using either.